# Woocommerce returning order total with &#36 instead $ currency simbol

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm converting some woocommerce order details from php to javascript.

When I use the follow command, I get `&#36` instead `$`simbol in output data. I'm not sure if the problem is in php or javascript.

```
<?php
$total = wp_strip_all_tags(wc_price( $total ));
?>
<script>
document.write ('<?php echo $total;?>');
</script>
```

I want to get result as `$ 10,00` and not `&#36 10,00`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Although your code here works without problems, you will find the following in the [`wp_strip_all_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) description: - This differs from `strip_tags()` because it removes the contents of the `<script>` and `<style>` tags. E.g. `strip_tags( '<script>something</script>' )` will return ‘something’. `wp_strip_all_tags` will return ”. 
Does this make any difference to your code if you replace this? or if you removed `wp_strip_all_tags()` completely.

Comment: @7uc1f3r thanks for your reply. Using `strp_tags()` also return the same chars. I may need to remove it but I will lost amount format for decimals (ex.: `$ 10.50` will be returned `10.5`).